# Why are $a$ and $ab$ associates if $b$ is a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> The function $v(x)$ is a Euclidean function on an integral domain, $D$.
>
> Proof :
>
> - Suppose that $v(a) < v(ab)$. If $b$ were a unit, then $a$ and $ab$
>     would be associates.
> - We have $a = abu$ and $ab = au^{-1}$.
> - Then, by Condition 2 of an Euclidean Function, we have $v(ab) \leq v(abu) = v(a) \leq v(au^{-1}) = v(ab)$. Therefore, $v(a) \nless v(ab)$

My main question is, why are $a$ and $ab$ associates if $b$ is a unit in the first place? I'm trying to understand how $a\mid ab$ = $ab\mid a$ if $b$ is a unit.

$$a = ab \implies b = aa^{-1} \implies 1 = aa^{-1} = b?$$

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Clearly, $a\mid ab$. If $b$ is a unit, $a = ab\cdot b^{-1}$, so $ab\mid a$ as well. Hence $a$ and $ab$ are associates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, wouldn't $ab^{-1} = abb^{-1} \implies ab^{-1} = a?$. Since you have to multiply both sides by $b^{-1}$.

Comment: If $a$ is not a unit, there is no $a^{-1}$. In particular, the implication you wrote down ($a = ab \implies 1 = b$) is false.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $x, y \in R$.

We say $x$ *divides* $y$ (or $y$ is a *multiple* of $x$) if there is $z \in R$ such that $y = xz$; we denote this by $x \mid y$.

We say $x$ and $y$ are *associates* (or *associate elements*) if $x \mid y$ and $y \mid x$.

---

First of all $a \mid ab$ by definition. On the other hand, as $b$ is a unit, it has a multiplicative inverse $b^{-1}$, so we have $$a = a1 = a(bb^{-1}) = (ab)b^{-1}.$$ By the first definition, we see that $ab \mid a$ (take $x = ab$, $y = a$, and $z = b^{-1}$). As $a \mid ab$ and $ab \mid a$, we see that $a$ and $ab$ are associates.