# Units in a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I want to prove that if $R$ is a Euclidean domain, with Euclidean function $d$, then if $a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and $b$ is not a unit then $d(a)<d(ab)$.

I already proved that $b$ is not a unit if and only if $d(b)>d(1)$. Most likely I need to use this, but I don't see how.

Can you give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that $d$ is not taken to be multiplicative?

Comment: $d$ is not (necessarily) multiplicative.

Comment: I disagree with "$b$ is not a unit if and only if $d(b)>1$".  In a polynomial ring $k[x]$, we have that $d(x)=1$ even though $x$ is not a unit.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I wanted to write $d(b)>d(1)$ (not $d(b)>1$). Here, in $d(1)$, $1$ denotes the one of the domain.

Comment: Does your definition of $d$ include the property that $d(a) \le d(ab)$ for $a,b \ne 0$? Having this produces a nice simple proof, but is not always considered to be part of the definition of a Euclidian function.

Comment: The question has already been asked. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201012/in-a-euclidean-domain-show-that-for-nonzero-a-b-in-d-va-vab-iff-b

Answer (score 0):

We aim to show that $d(a) = d(ab) \implies $ b is a unit. Consider $(a)$ and $(ab)$. If $(a) = (ab)$ we are done. Now consider $(ab) \subset (a) $ So $\exists c \in (a) $ st $ c \not\in (ab)$ now apply division with remainder property $ c =(ab)q+r $ but now $d(r) < d(ab) \leq d(a) $ which is a contradiction as r∈(a) and d(x)≤d(xy)∀x,y so $(a)=(ab) \implies $ b is a unit as required.

Comment: Sorry, but I find your argument impossible to follow. First, you use $d$ with two meanings, but that is easily fixable. What I do not understand is: 1) why $d(r) < d(ab)$?; 2) why $r \ne 0$? (is this a consequence of 1)?); 3) why do you deduce $(a) = (ab)$?

Comment: You can only deduce $d(r) < d(c)$, but not $d(r) < d(ab)$. For instance if $a = b = X$, $c = X^3 + X$ and $d = \deg$ then $q=0$ and $r = X^2$, so $d(r) = d(ab) =2$. I think that this invalidates your argument beyond salvation.

Comment: sorry I meant to divide c by ab. and now we can see that d(r) < d(ab)

Comment: 1) So d(r) < d(ab) by division axiom. 2) If r = 0 then c is in (ab) and 3) if r is in a then d(r) can't be less than d(a) so we have our contradiction.

Comment: Now, with your correction, I understand your reasoning. I have also canceled my downvote.